'Service Setup' is not visible in Unlimited Edition Saleforce Org
I have upgraded my Salesforce Org from Enterprise to Unlimited Edition. I also went through the Service Setup Assistant, but still the 'Service Setup' option is visible when clicking the gear icon. As well, I'm not able to access all the features of Lightning Knowledge, like question and answer fields that are not setup automatically.
Any help is appreciated.

Does the logged in user has any one permission set mentioned in this link ?
